# Does the English version of Btooom! end at Chapter 88?

Tags: btooom

Does the English version of the Btooom! Manga end at Chapter 88?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. the reason you think so is because you're looking at the Scanlation.

the reason why i suspect this is because looking at [Manga Update's entry on  Btooom!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=45009) shows that the scanlation by S2scans & JazzWay Team stops at Chapter 88 which is Volume 18

However the same page also indicates that Btooom! has been lienced by Yen press who have only released up to Volume 16 with [Volume 17](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/none/btooom-vol-17/9780316502856/?yen) due to be released near the end of May 2017 in the US

[image: Btooom! Volume 17]

while Yen Press only lists up to [Volume 18](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/none/btooom-vol-18/9780316502870/?yen) (as of 21/03/2017) Manga Updates indicates there are 22 Volumes and is on-going, confirmed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btooom!#Volume_list) with Volume 22 having been release January 7th 2017 in Japan

```
No. |   Japanese release date   |   Japanese ISBN
-------------------------------------------------------------
22  |   January 7, 2017         |   ISBN 978-4-10-771949-2
```

So to summarize, the localized and licenced version of Btooom currently (as of 21/03/2017) ends at Volume 16 which stops at Chapter 81 however release by Yen press is on-going and more volumes are expected to be released. any release after this outside Yen press currently is not an official copy.

UPDATE: as of the 17/8/2017, Wikipedia lists that the english version of Volume 19 is due November 14, 2017. this can further be confirmed on [Yen Press's Website for Volume 19](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/none/btooom-vol-19/9780316412780/?yen). also looking at the [series](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/series/btooom/?yen) in general on their website they have up to Volume 21, however Volume 21 doesn't have any Paperback or Eletronic links so looking at [Volume 20](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/none/btooom-vol-20/9780316520584/?yen) it's expected to be out February 20th, 2018.

As such this is more or less confirmation that the english version of Btooom! will not end at Chapter 88 as Chapter 88, as explained above, is in Volume 18

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! I just have one follow up question. So you're saying that it just hasn't been released yet in the US right? Thanks

Comment: @JamesFox correct. Chapter 88, found in Volume 18, is expected to be released (according to Yen press) 22th of August 2017 and given the series is on-going we can probably expect it not to end there

Comment: Thanks Bro I don't know how the point system works here so I can't reward you haha anyway thanks for your time

Comment: @JamesFox you can read up on how the reputation system works in the [help center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: How can i see yen press releases?

Comment: @EgharAmki either by going to the Yen Press website [here](http://yenpress.com/) or by checking out their list of licensed series on [manga updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/publishers.html?id=279). Yen Press doesn't seem to sell though their website but they link to the product pages of the sites that sell what you are looking at